# How can I collapse these fields and rows in this result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've written this query to aggregate data from several tables I want the result set to be grouped by caseID, but in the event of multiple rows (a possibility, I want to do some combination of fields.

For example I want all the tooth Numbers for a particular case  to be combined into one tring that is comma separated and all caseID  records that are the same to have that toothstring. I also want the Minimum of the MaterialID and let be shown in all records that have the same caseID

I've got an update that seems to do a partial update of the toothstring, but does not handle all records.

Kind of like this example (There are more fields than this as seen in the SQL below):

```
CaseID  Material    Tooth
12345   1   12
12345   2   13
12345   2   1
12345   4   5

CaseID  Material    Tooth
12345   1   1,5,12,13
12345   1   1,5,12,13
12345   1   1,5,12,13
12345   1   1,5,12,13
```

Here's my SQL:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#tScanRemake') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tScanRemake

Create Table #tScanRemake
(
ScanOrderUID VarChar( 100)
,ModelElementUID VarChar (100)
,ToothElementUID VarChar (100)
,ScanOrderCaseID VarChar (50)
,CasesCaseID VarChar (50)
,RemakeID Varchar (20)
,ReasonID VarChar (10)
,Reason VarChar (50)
,IntOrderID VarChar (100)
,ExtOrderID VarChar (100)
,OperatorName VarChar (100)
,ScanSource VarChar (50)
,DatabaseID INT
,MachineGroupID INT
,ToothNumber Varchar (50)
,Shade Varchar (20)
,Anterior_Posterior Varchar (20)
,Items  VarChar (50)
,IsBridge Bit
,ScanMaterialID INT
,ProcessStatusID  VarChar (150)
,DateIn DateTime
,DateInvoiced DateTime
,DoctorID Varchar (20)
,DoctorFirstName Varchar (50)
,DoctorLastName Varchar (50)
,PatientFirstName Varchar (50)
,PatientLastName Varchar (50)
)

Insert Into #tScanRemake

SELECT distinct top 1000
 so.ScanOrderUID
,se. ModelElementUID
,st. ToothElementUID
,so. CaseID ScanOrderCaseID
,c. CaseID
,c. RemakeID
,c. ReasonID
,r. Reason
,so. IntOrderID
,so. ExtOrderID
,so. OperatorName
,so. ScanSource
,so. DatabaseID
,so. MachineGroupID
,st. ToothNumber
,c. Shade
,CASE WHEN GDLControl.dbo. fn_HasAnteriorTeeth(GDLControl .dbo. fn_ConvertCSVToBitMaskTally(GDLControl .dbo. fn_ParseTeethStrings(st .ToothNumber), ',')) = 1
     THEN 'Anterior'
     ELSE 'Posterior'
 END AS Anterior_Posterior
,se. Items
,CASE WHEN se. Items like '%Bridge%'
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
 END as IsBridge  
,se. ScanMaterialID
,so. ProcessStatusID
,c. DateIn
,c. DateInvoiced
,c. DoctorID
,d. FirstName as DoctorFirstname
,d. LastName as DoctorLastname
,c. PatientFirst
,c. PatientLast

FROM 
[3ShapeScanOrders] AS so WITH (NOLOCK)
Left Outer Join
[LS-DLPlus].[DLPlus] .[dbo]. [Cases] AS c  WITH (NOLOCK )
       ON so. CaseID =  c .RemakeOf  AND c.remakeof >''
Left outer   JOIN
[LS-DLPlus].[DLPlus] .[dbo]. [Reasons] AS r  WITH (NOLOCK )
    ON c. ReasonID = R .ReasonID
Left Outer JOIN
[LS-DLPlus].[DLPlus] .[dbo]. [Doctors] AS d  WITH (NOLOCK )
    ON d. DoctorID = c .DoctorID
INNER JOIN
[3ShapeScanModelElements] AS se WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON so. ScanOrderUID = se .ScanOrderUID
INNER JOIN
[3ShapeScanToothElements] AS st WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON so. ScanOrderUID = st .ScanOrderUID      

Where
so.CaseID >''

--Insert Into [GDLDatamart].[dbo].[Shape3ScanRemake]

--Select
--ScanOrderUID
--,ModelElementUID
--,ToothElementUID
--,ScanOrderCaseID
--,Remakeof
--,ReasonID
--,Reason
--,IntOrderID
--,ExtOrderID
--,OperatorName
--,ScanSource
--,DatabaseID
--,MachineGroupID
--,ToothElementTypeID
--,ToothNumber
--,Items 
--,ModelHeight
--,ScanMaterialID
--,VirtualItem
--,ProcessStatusID 
--,OrderasofLocalDTS
--,OrdersasofUTC
----,OrdersModifiedLocalDTS
----,OrdersModifiedUTC
--,ElementasofLocalDTS
--,ElementasofUTC
--,ToothasofLocalDTS
--,ToothasofUTC

Select *
from #tScanRemake

--Where ScanordercaseID = 1014535612
--Group by ScanOrdercaseID

--Go
--Update ToothString    
UPDATE tsr
SET tsr. ToothNumber = tsr .ToothNumber + ',' + t2. ToothNumber
FROM #tScanRemake tsr
     CROSS JOIN #tScanRemake t2
WHERE Exists (SELECT Distinct ScanOrderUID , ToothNumber
               FROM #tScanRemake t
               WHERE
                 ToothNumber < tsr. ToothNumber
                 AND ScanOrderUID = tsr.ScanOrderUID ) 

--Go

--Select *
--from #tScanRemake
--Where ScanOrderUID = '97D7FB5F-3129-E211-931A-001D09F2CB34'
```

Comment: If you're looking to comma-concatenate in SQL Server, you can use the `FORXML` trick, explained [here](http://sqlserverjunction.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/how-to-use-for-xml-path-to-concatenate-strings-in-t-sql/) or on several SO posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
caseid, 
MIN(material) Min_Material,
(select  CAST(tooth AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' from tt b WHERE a.caseid=b.caseid FOR XML PATH('') ) list
FROM tt a
GROUP BY caseid
```

- tt is your table

Comment: Thank You JayVee. That did the trick. I'd never heard of FOR XML Path before.